# Lazy Loading using MyBatis 3 with Java

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

I am using Mybatis (3.2.7 version) as an ORM framework for my JAVA project.
As I'm from JPA background, I was keen to explore the LAZYLOADING supported by Mybatis.
But I couldn't get across anything substantial.

**(I am configuring MYBATIS using JAVA API and annotations solely for querying purpose)**

As per the Mybatis documentation: 

***1. lazyLoadingEnabled: default value=TRUE***

Globally enables or disables lazy loading. When enabled, all relations will be lazily 
loaded. This value can be superseded for an specific relation by using the **fetchType** attribute 
on it.

**2. aggressiveLazyLoading : default value=TRUE**

When enabled, an object with lazy loaded properties will be loaded entirely upon a call to any of the lazy properties. Otherwise, each property is loaded on demand.

Using the following attributes, I tried the following code:

a. JAVA Classes :

Feedback.java

```
public class Feedback implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int id;
private String message;

   /**
   * while loading Feedback, I want sender object to be lazily loaded
   */
private User sender;
private boolean seen;

// getters and setters
}
```

User.java

```
public class User implements Serializable, {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int id;
private String email;

// getters and setters
}
```

b. DB schema:

Feedback table

```
                Table "public.feedback"

  Column | Type      |    Modifiers                       
-------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer   | PRIMARY KEY
 seen        | boolean   | not null
 sender_id   | integer   | FOREIGN KEY (sender_id) REFERENCES users(id)
 message     | text      |
```

User Table:

```
                Table "public.users"

Column   | Type     |     Modifiers                      
-------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------
id          | integer  | PRIMARY KEY
email       | text     |
```

c. Configuring MyBatis via JAVA API:

```
DataSource dataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource();
        ((PGSimpleDataSource) dataSource).setServerName("localhost");
        ((PGSimpleDataSource) dataSource).setDatabaseName(dbName);
        ((PGSimpleDataSource) dataSource).setPortNumber(5432);
        ((PGSimpleDataSource) dataSource).setUser(new UnixSystem().getUsername());
        ((PGSimpleDataSource) dataSource).setPassword("");

        TransactionFactory transactionFactory = new JdbcTransactionFactory();
        Environment environment = new Environment(dbName, transactionFactory, dataSource);
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration(environment);
             configuration.addMapper(FeedbackMapper.class);

            //
             configuration.setAggressiveLazyLoading(false);
             sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(configuration);
```

d. Querying DB and DB Queries in Feedbackmapper:

d.1 Code in Feedbackmapper:

```
@Select("SELECT f.id, f.message, f.seen, f.sender_id FROM feedback f WHERE f.id= #{feedbackId}")
@Results(value = { 
        @Result(property = "id", column = "id"),
        @Result(property = "sender", column = "sender_id", javaType = User.class, one = @One(select = "getUser", fetchType=FetchType.DEFAULT))
})
public Feedback getFeedback(@Param("feedbackId") int feedbackId);

@Select("SELECT id, email FROM users WHERE id=#{id}")
public User getUser(int id);
```

d.2: Code to invoke the queries in feedbackMapper

```
    // setup Mybatis session factory and config
    Feedback feedback =feedbackMapper.getFeedback(70000);
    System.out.println(feedback);
```

**But still the "sender"  object is populated upon querying the getFeedback(id). I expect the sender object shouldn't be populated immediately but only when I call getSender() on the fetched feedback object . Please help**.

My recent Observations:

Mybatis team has indeed got it wrong in their documentation ie in documentation:

1. lazyLoadingEnabled: default value=TRUE
2. aggressiveLazyLoading : default value=TRUE

   But looking at their source code:

   ```
    protected boolean lazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    protected boolean aggressiveLazyLoading = true;
   ```

   **However that being corrected, the results are not affected and lazy loading isnt working :( **

Answer (score 7):

I think I found a way to enable the lazyloading (though not cent-percent sure):

- **MyBatis documentation has following setting in configuration:**

Setting : lazyLoadTriggerMethods

Description : Specifies which Object's methods trigger a lazy load

Valid Values : A method name list separated by commas

Default:  equals,clone,hashCode,toString

- As per the source code, this thing maps properly to what is given in documentation:

  ```
  public class Configuration {
  // other attributes + methods
  protected Set<String> lazyLoadTriggerMethods = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new         
  String[] { "equals", "clone", "hashCode", "toString" }));
  }
  ```

  - **I have changed the Mybatis configuration to follows:**

    ```
    TransactionFactory transactionFactory = new JdbcTransactionFactory();
    Environment environment = new Environment(dbName, transactionFactory,  dataSource);
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(environment);

    /**
    *This is the cause why LAZY LOADING is working now
    */
      configuration.getLazyLoadTriggerMethods().clear();

      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
      configuration.setLazyLoadingEnabled(true);
      configuration.setAggressiveLazyLoading(false);
    ```
  - **The queries in Mapper (mostly unchanged)**:

    ```
    @Select("SELECT id, message, seen, sender_id 
    FROM feedback WHERE f.id= #{feedbackId}")
    @Results(value = { 
       @Result(property = "id", column = "id"),
       @Result(property = "sender", column = "sender_id", javaType = User.class, one = @One(select = "getUser"))

    // Set fetchType as DEFAULT or LAZY or don't set at all-- lazy loading takes place
    // Set fetchType as EAGER --sender Object is loaded immediately

    })
    public Feedback getFeedback(@Param("feedbackId") int feedbackId);

    @Select("SELECT id, email FROM users WHERE id=#{id}")
    public User getUser(int id);
    ```

- **JAVA Code to invoke mapper**

```
        FeedbackMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(FeedbackMapper.class);
        Feedback feedback =mapper.getFeedback(69999);                   
        System.out.println("1. Feedback object before sender lazily load: \n"+ feedback);
        System.out.println("2. Sender loaded explicitly \n" +feedback.getSender());
        System.out.println("3. Feedback object after sender loading \n" + feedback);
```

- Output of the CODE

*1. Feedback object before sender lazily load:*

```
{id : 69999,  message : message123, sender : null, seen : false}

2. Sender loaded explicitly 

{id : 65538 , email: hemant@gmail.com}

3. Feedback object after sender loading:

{id : 69999, message : message123, sender : {id : 65538, email : hemant@gmail.com},
 seen : false}
```

- **Though this works satisfactorily, upon doing**

`configuration.getLazyLoadTriggerMethods().clear();`

However to lack of documentation in Mybatis, I'm not sure, whether this is associated with any drawbacks as such.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

I looked into the source code, and the problem is that the Configuration class does not reflect the doc.

In configuration class, lazy load is disabled by default. This changed in commit [f8ddba364092d819f100e0e8f7dec677c777d588](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/commit/f8ddba364092d819f100e0e8f7dec677c777d588), but the doc was not updated to reflect the change.

```
protected boolean lazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

I filled a bug report https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/214.

For now, add configuration.setLazyLoadingEnabled(true) to enable lazy load.

Old answer:

The documentation is incorrect. When aggressiveLazyLoading is true, all lazy properties are loaded after any method call on the object.
So calling feedback.toString() will fetch the Feedback's sender property.

You should set aggressiveLazyLoading to false to achieve what you want.

Comment: //
             configuration.setAggressiveLazyLoading(false);
             sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(configuration);

SIR thats already done in my configuration settings :(

Comment: I incorrectly assumed you used aggressive lazy load.
It's possible the default FetchType is incorrect and does not reflect the actual configuration. Setting the FetchType to lazy should be a workaround for now.

Comment: It was FetchType.LAZY initially, but to no avail :(

Comment: I updated my answer as lazy load is disabled by default. Try enabling it by calling configuration.setLazyLoadingEnabled(true). The docs will be updated soon.

Comment: **Yes you are right.**


 Mybatis team has indeed got it wrong in their documentation ie in 
documentaion:


 `1. lazyLoadingEnabled: default value=TRUE` 
 `2. aggressiveLazyLoading : default value=TRUE`
 But looking at their source code: 
`protected boolean lazyLoadingEnabled = false;` 
`protected boolean aggressiveLazyLoading = true;`

 **However that being corrected, the results are not affected and lazy loading isnt working :( **

Comment: You mean that after setting lazy loading to true and aggressive lazy to false, the sender property is still loaded by these two lines of code?
Feedback feedback =feedbackMapper.getFeedback(70000);
System.out.println(feedback);

That's unusual... Do you know if it worked in an older version? I did this kind of tests with MyBatis 3.0.6 and CGLIB and it worked perfectly. So it either worked before or there is an error with your configuration but I don't see any in the files you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not easy to use `print` to verify the lazy loading in mybatis.
We can use `configuration.getLazyLoadTriggerMethods().clear();` to remove the default triggerMethods as the previous answer. But when we print it, or using `toString`, It still will call `getXXX`. so It still trigger lazy loading to select more. So we can't debug or print to see the procedure to lazy loading.

I found a way to verify this function.

1. set log level to debug.
2. write the follow codes and see the console.

```
        log.info("user :{}", userLazyDepartment);
        log.info("user :{}", userLazyDepartment.getDepartment());
```